# Apache Spark with Cassandra behavior

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, notserializableexception

I am writing a standalone Spark program that gets its data from Cassandra.
I followed the examples and created the RDD via the newAPIHadoopRDD() and the ColumnFamilyInputFormat class.
The RDD is created, but I get a NotSerializableException when I call the RDD's .groupByKey() method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
    sparkConf.setMaster("local").setAppName("Test");
    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    Job job = new Job();
    Configuration jobConf = job.getConfiguration();
    job.setInputFormatClass(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.class);

    ConfigHelper.setInputInitialAddress(jobConf, host);
    ConfigHelper.setInputRpcPort(jobConf, port);
    ConfigHelper.setOutputInitialAddress(jobConf, host);
    ConfigHelper.setOutputRpcPort(jobConf, port);
    ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(jobConf, keySpace, columnFamily, true);
    ConfigHelper.setInputPartitioner(jobConf,"Murmur3Partitioner");
    ConfigHelper.setOutputPartitioner(jobConf,"Murmur3Partitioner");

    SlicePredicate predicate = new SlicePredicate();
    SliceRange sliceRange = new SliceRange();
    sliceRange.setFinish(new byte[0]);
    sliceRange.setStart(new byte[0]);
    predicate.setSlice_range(sliceRange);
    ConfigHelper.setInputSlicePredicate(jobConf, predicate);

    JavaPairRDD<ByteBuffer, SortedMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn>> rdd =
    spark.newAPIHadoopRDD(jobConf,
    ColumnFamilyInputFormat.class.asSubclass(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat.class),
    ByteBuffer.class, SortedMap.class);

    JavaPairRDD<ByteBuffer, Iterable<SortedMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn>>> groupRdd = rdd.groupByKey();
    System.out.println(groupRdd.count());
}
```

The exception:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
>   at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
>   at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(BlockObjectWriter.scala:179)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask$$anonfun$runTask$1.apply(ShuffleMapTask.scala:161)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask$$anonfun$runTask$1.apply(ShuffleMapTask.scala:158)
>   at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
>   at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:158)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
>   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

What I am trying to do is to merge all row key columns into a single entry.
I also get the same exception when I try to use the reduceByKey() method like so:

```
JavaPairRDD<ByteBuffer, SortedMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn>> reducedRdd = rdd.reduceByKey(
    new Function2<SortedMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn>, SortedMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn>, sortedMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn>>() {
        public SortedMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn> call(SortedMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn> arg0,
            SortedMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn> arg1) throws Exception {
            SortedMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn> sortedMap = new TreeMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn>(arg0.comparator());
            sortedMap.putAll(arg0);
            sortedMap.putAll(arg1);
            return sortedMap;
        }
    }
);
```

I am using:

- spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop1
- Cassandra 1.2.12
- Java 1.6

Does anyone know what the problem is?
What is it there that fails the serialization?

Thanks, 
Shai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is caused probably by trying to serialise ByteBuffers. They are not serialisable and you need to convert them to arrays of bytes before producing RDD.

You should try official DataStax Cassandra driver for Spark which is available [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector)

Comment: Hi Jacek, Thank you for your response. My solution was exactly that.